# adding to database oledb c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, oledb

After searching for about an hour it appears this is the correct way to use the oledb libary to insert a record to an access database however it doesnt work for me , HELP...

```
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        // TODO: Modify the connection string and include any
        // additional required properties for your database.
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = \\crd-a555-015.occ.local\c$\Users\james.piper\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project V1\Project Database.accdb";
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Work_Done (employee,client,project,task,hours)" + " VALUES (@employee,@client,@project,@task,@hours)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee", user.employee);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project", listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@task", listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hours", listBox4.SelectedItem.ToString());



            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("sql insert fail");
        }
```

Comment: you're going to need to define "doesnt work". You get an error? Unexpected behaviour? Something isn't executed as you thought? We need some more detailed information.

Comment: What error message are you getting??

Comment: As far as I can remember, OleDb does not support named parameters, only ordinal parameters. Therefor, you should change your query to use question marks (`?`) instead of parameter names. Also, you should get used to use all your IDisposables inside `using` statements - OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand are IDisposable.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Not supported, but it won't throw an error.  It will just convert the parameter name into a ? behind the scenes.  Parameters have to be in index order, which, in this case, they are.

Comment: @LarsTech Good to know, in case one day I'll have to work with OleDb again :-)

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("sql insert fail");` <= If you are getting an Exception then you are hiding all the details of why the Exception occurred with this line. If you can't handle the Exception then do not catch it or re-throw it with `throw;` statement.

Comment: Your cmd object isn't using the conn connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this code like this:

```
var connectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = \\crd-a555-015.occ.local\c$\Users\james.piper\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project V1\Project Database.accdb";
var query = "INSERT INTO Work_Done (employee,client,project,task,hours) VALUES (@employee,@client,@project,@task,@hours)";
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{             
    using(var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
        // No need to specifiy command type, since CommandType.Text is the default

        // I'm assuming, of course, your parameter data types. You should change them if my assumptions are wrong.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@employee", OleDbType.Integer).Value = user.employee;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@client", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@project", OleDbType.Integer).Value =  Convert.ToInt32(listBox2.SelectedItem);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@task", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(listBox3.SelectedItem);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@hours", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(listBox4.SelectedItem);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"sql insert fail: {ex}");
        }
    }                
}
```

The major changes are these:

1. use the `Using` statement for each instance of a class that implements the `IDisposable` interface.
2. Using constructors with parameters to make the code shorter (and more readable, IMHO).
3. Note that the constructor of the OleDbCommand also has the OleDbConnection object. In your code, you didn't specify the active connection to the command.
4. Adding parameters with `Add` and not `AddWithValue`. Read [this blog post](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) to find out why.

Comment: sql insert fail: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): Parameter @client has no default value.

Comment: Check the values you send. P

Comment: I did a console.writeline of listbox1.selecteditem.tostring and it prints out the correct value i dont understand how it is then a 'null' value later on

Comment: I Don't know what it should be, nor do I know what does your code look like right now. It's impossible to debug by telepathy....

Comment: as an unrelated question what is the correct syntax to add parameters to a select statement as ive tried to copy the format of the insert  and I get this error (sql insert fail: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at testing_sql.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\james.piper\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\testing sql\testing sql\Form1.cs:line 236  ) 'code'   Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it